# Neo4j: Recursive query for simple node structure

Tags: neo4j, cypher, recursive-query

Let us say we have a entity/node structure:

```
Emp: e_id, e_name, e_bossid
```

In Neo4j I have nodes with this structure and relationship `e_bossid->[reports_to]->e_id`.
I want to construct a recursive query in neo4j that would be equivalent to the following sql recursive query:

```
 WITH RECURSIVE Emp_CTE AS (
        SELECT e_id, e_name, e_bossid, w_id, w_s1, w_s2, w_s3, w_s4, w_s5
        FROM empfull
        WHERE e_bossid IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT e.e_id, e.e_name, e.e_bossid, e.w_id, e.w_s1, e.w_s2, e.w_s3, e.w_s4, e.w_s5
        FROM empfull e
        INNER JOIN Emp_CTE ecte ON ecte.e_id = e.e_bossid
)

SELECT *
FROM Emp_CTE LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1
;
```

**How would this query look like in Neo4j cypher?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
// Mark the root (aka `e_bossid IS NULL`)
MATCH (e:Employee) WHERE NOT (e)-[:REPORTS_TO]->()
SET e:Root

// find all paths of arbitrary length from he root
MATCH path = (b:Root)<-[:REPORTS_TO*]-(e:Employee)
RETURN path
limit 1000
```

Answer (score 3):

Or if you don't want to mark any of the nodes with a `Root` label you could just do it all inline but it might be a bit slower than Michael's version

```
MATCH path = (e:Employee)<-[:REPORTS_TO*]-(e:Employee)
WHERE NOT (e)-[:REPORTS_TO]->()
RETURN path
limit 1000
```

We have an example of [translating the Northwind database to a graph](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/) and it has a similar reporting structure. Might be worth a look.